# Make Applications open the Overview Screen

Tags: gnome, gui

When clicking "Applications" on the top-left in Fedora the overview screen appears.

However in CentOS this opens a Windows-like start menu.

Is there any way to make this open the overview screen instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why Gnome behave differently in Centos compared to Fedora is because Centos uses Gnome classic and Fedora use the "regular" gnome as default.

To get the "overview screen" instead, you just have to logout and select "Gnome" instead of "Gnome classic", see figure below.

[image]

Comment: For some reason Fedora is not showing the gear icon.  It is a fresh install with one user - nothing special.

Comment: Problem solved.

Comment: BAR I used to have the same problem in Arch Linux. However, now the gear icon is showing up.  Maybe some Gnome issue that got fixed.  I don't which version of Gnome Fedora uses, I currently use Gnome 3.16.3.